# LISTAGG IN PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, listagg

Help please find mistake in creating function which will return one row from list.

```
SELECT   listagg(' ' || V_RECEIVING_LIST.DOCUMENT_NUMBER || CHR(13))
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY V_RECEIVING_LIST.DOCUMENT_NUMBER)
FROM     svc.claim_detail, tbc.v_receiving_list
WHERE    claim_detail.id_claim = 334455 
         AND V_RECEIVING_LIST.ID_RECEIVING_LIST = CLAIM_DETAIL.ID_RECEIVING_LIST
```

The code return correct result.

But the next dont return the same.

```
DECLARE
    scodes   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
    SELECT (LISTAGG(' ' || RECEIVING_LIST.DOCUMENT_NUMBER || CHR(13))
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY RECEIVING_LIST.DOCUMENT_NUMBER))
    INTO   scodes 
    FROM   svc.claim_detail, tbc.v_receiving_list  
    WHERE  claim_detail.id_claim = 334455 
         AND RECEIVING_LIST.ID_RECEIVING_LIST = CLAIM_DETAIL.ID_RECEIVING_LIST;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(scodes);
END;
```

Comment: What does the PL/SQL block display? What does the SQL query return?

Comment: Your example "answer" below only shows one row output (that I can see).  So what's the problem?
What is the standalone SQL returning that's different from your answer below?

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> select * from V_RECEIVING_LIST ;

DOCUMENT_NUMBER ID_RECEIVING_LIST
--------------- --------------------
              1 a
              1 a
              2 b

SQL> select * from claim_detail ;

  ID_CLAIM ID_RECEIVING_LIST
---------- --------------------
       123 a
       123 a
       124 b


SQL> DECLARE
  2      scodes   VARCHAR2 (4000);
  3  BEGIN
  4      SELECT (LISTAGG(' '|| v_receiving_list.DOCUMENT_NUMBER || CHR(13))
  5             WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v_receiving_list.DOCUMENT_NUMBER))
  6
  7      INTO   scodes
  8      FROM   claim_detail, v_receiving_list
  9      WHERE  claim_detail.id_claim = 123
 10      AND v_receiving_list.ID_RECEIVING_LIST = CLAIM_DETAIL.ID_RECEIVING_LIST;
 11
 12
 13      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The output is '||scodes);
 14  END;
 15  /
 1e output is  1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```